# login into Spotify through python requests module

Tags: python

I've been trying to connect my Spotify account using the requests module and I  came across a problem

[image: the header]

[image]

later on I tried to manipulate it on my Python code

```
import requests

URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/login/password'
payload = {
  "username": "example@gmail.com",
  "password": "123456",
  "remember" : True 
}

response = requests.post(URL , json=payload)
print(response.status_code)



OUTPUT : 415
```

what went wrong ?

Comment: Error 415 means Unsupported Media Type

Comment: You're sending it JSON and the page you're using is a form that probably communicates with the backend via a POST with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is how you should interact with Spotify from code.
[It has an API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/) and you should use tokens for authentication or anything else from password.

Anyway you can try setting the correct media type when making the request:

```
URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/login/password'
payload = {
  "username": "example@gmail.com",
  "password": "123456",
  "remember" : True 
}
headers = { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

response = requests.post(URL , json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: ```python 
b'{"error":"errorCSRF","error_description":"invalid csrf","BON":["0","0",2146342393]}'
```
im getting this error

Comment: That's why I said that you should use the API for this purpose. Anyway if the answer solved your original problem, can you please mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use this url to send post request as it has "recaptchaToken" which you need pass in your payload which is getting generated dynamically. Hence it is not a good idea to use this approach.

Instead you can use API to achieve the same.

```
https://github.com/plamere/spotipy
```